# optim gives poor fit to data in R

Tags: r, optimization

I try to optimise `U48meas` and `Th0U8meas` using the function `optim` in R, but as you can see with the code below, the result is rather poor: the resulting `U48calc` and `Th0U8calc` are far away from target `U48meas` and `Th0U8meas`values, respectively.

Does anyone have any tips on how to improve the fit?

```
rm(list=ls())

library(deSolve)

l <- 0.5 # bone 1/2 thickness (cm)
x_vec <- c(0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.30, 0.45) # distance along the bone (cm)
U48meas <- c(1.195, 1.197, 1.199, 1.201, 1.209) # measured (234U/238U)
Th0U8meas <- c(0.43, 0.44, 0.46, 0.47, 0.51) # measured (230Th/238U)

paraminit <- c(5*10e-13, 10e3, 1.2) # initial parameters: D/R, age (yr) and (234U/238U) at the surface
lowerbound <- c(1e-14, 1e4, 1) # minimum values: D/R, age (yr) and (234U/238U) at the surface
upperbound <- c(1e-12, 60e3, 1.3) # maximum values: D/R, age (yr) and (234U/238U) at the surface

A1_0 <- 0.025 # (238U) activity at the surface of the bone (disintegrations per second)

l234 <- 2.8262e-6/(365.25*24*3600) # 234U decay constant (s-1)
l230 <- 9.1577e-6/(365.25*24*3600) # 230Th decay constant (s-1)

length_series <- 100 # number of n in the series sum

funmin <- function(x) {
  K <- x[1] # D/R diffusion coefficient/volumetric equilibirum constant
  t <- x[2] # age in yr
  t <- t*(365.25*24*3600) # convert age to seconds
  U48_0 <- x[3] # (234U/238U) at the surface
  A2_0 <- U48_0*A1_0 # (234U) activity at the surface (disintegrations per second)
  DA2_0 <- A2_0 - A1_0 # (234U) activity excess at the surface of the bone (disintegrations per second)

  # create vectors
  series238 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
  series234 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
  series230 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
  beta234 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
  beta230 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
  gamma <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
  A1 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(x_vec))
  DA2 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(x_vec))
  A3 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(x_vec))
  f <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(x_vec))

  i <- 0

  for (x in x_vec){
    for (n in 0:length_series){
      # series238[n+1] <- (-1)^n/(2*n + 1)*exp(-K*((2*n + 1)^2)*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
      series238[n+1] <- (-1)/(2*n + 1)*exp(-K*((2*n + 1)^2)*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
      beta234[n+1] <- 1 + 4*l234*(l^2)/((2*n + 1)^2)*pi^2*K
      beta230[n+1] <- l230 - l234 - K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2/(4*l^2)
      gamma[n+1] <- l230*(1/(beta230[n+1] + l234) + (U48_0 - 1)*exp(-l234*t)/(beta234[n+1]*beta230[n+1]))
      # series234[n+1] <- (-1)^n/((2*n + 1)*beta234[n+1])*exp(-l234*t-K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
      # series230[n+1] <- (-1)^n/(2*n + 1)*gamma[n+1]*exp(-K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
      series234[n+1] <- (-1)/((2*n + 1)*beta234[n+1])*exp(-l234*t-K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
      series230[n+1] <- (-1)/(2*n + 1)*gamma[n+1]*exp(-K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
    }
    sum_series238 <- sum(series238)  
    sum_series234 <- sum(series234)  
    sum_series230 <- sum(series230)
    i <- i+1
    A1[i] <- A1_0*(1 - 4/pi*sum_series238) # (238U) activity (disintegrations per second)
    DA2[i] <- DA2_0*(cosh(x*(l234/K)^0.5)/(cosh(l*l234/K)^0.5) - 4/pi*sum_series234) # (234U) activity excess (disintegrations per second)

    # calculate 'f' used to calculate A3
    t0 <- 0
    series230_0 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
    beta234_0 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
    beta230_0 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
    gamma_0 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
    for (n in 0:length_series){
      beta234_0[n+1] <- 1 + 4*l234*(l^2)/((2*n + 1)^2)*pi^2*K
      beta230_0[n+1] <- l230 - l234 - K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2/(4*l^2)
      gamma_0[n+1] <- l230*(1/(beta230[n+1] + l234) + (U48_0 - 1)*exp(-l234*t0)/(beta234[n+1]*beta230[n+1]))
      # series230_0[n+1] <- (-1)^n/(2*n + 1)*gamma[n+1]*exp(-K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2*t0/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
      series230_0[n+1] <- (-1)/(2*n + 1)*gamma[n+1]*exp(-K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2*t0/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
    }
    sum_series230_0 <- sum(series230_0)
    f[i] <- - A1_0*(1 + (U48_0 - 1)*cosh(x*(l234/K)^0.5)/(cosh(l*(l234/K)^0.5) - 4/pi*sum_series230_0))*exp(-l230*t)
    A3[i] <- f[i] + A1_0*(1 + (U48_0 - 1)*cosh(x*(l234/K)^0.5)/(cosh(l*(l234/K)^0.5) - 4/pi*sum_series230)) # (230Th) activity (disintegrations per second)
  }
  A2 <- DA2 + A1 # (234U) activity (disintegrations per second)
  U48calc <- A2/A1 # (234U/238U)
  Th0U8calc <- A3/A1 # (230Th/238U)
  Th0U4calc <- A3/A2 # (230Th/234U)
  fmin <- sum((U48calc - U48meas)^2 + (Th0U8calc - Th0U8meas)^2 ) # function to minimise
}

sol <- optim(paraminit, funmin, method = "L-BFGS-B",
             lower = lowerbound, upper = upperbound)

print(sol) # display result of minimisation

#########################################################
# calculate ratios with solutions from minimisation

x_vec <- c(0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.30, 0.45)

K <- sol$par[1] # D/R diffusion coefficient/volumetric equilibirum constant
t <- sol$par[2] # age in yr
t <- t*(365.25*24*3600)
U48_0 <- sol$par[3]
A2_0 <- U48_0*A1_0
DA2_0 <- A2_0 - A1_0 # (234U) excess at the surface of the bone (disintegrations per second)

series238 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
series234 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
series230 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
beta234 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
beta230 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
gamma <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
A1 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(x_vec))
DA2 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(x_vec))
A3 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(x_vec))
f <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(x_vec))

i <- 0

for (x in x_vec){
  for (n in 0:length_series){
    # series238[n+1] <- (-1)^n/(2*n + 1)*exp(-K*((2*n + 1)^2)*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
    series238[n+1] <- (-1)/(2*n + 1)*exp(-K*((2*n + 1)^2)*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
    beta234[n+1] <- 1 + 4*l234*(l^2)/((2*n + 1)^2)*pi^2*K
    beta230[n+1] <- l230 - l234 - K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2/(4*l^2)
    gamma[n+1] <- l230*(1/(beta230[n+1] + l234) + (U48_0 - 1)*exp(-l234*t)/(beta234[n+1]*beta230[n+1]))
    # series234[n+1] <- (-1)^n/((2*n + 1)*beta234[n+1])*exp(-l234*t-K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
    # series230[n+1] <- (-1)^n/(2*n + 1)*gamma[n+1]*exp(-K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
    series234[n+1] <- (-1)/((2*n + 1)*beta234[n+1])*exp(-l234*t-K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
    series230[n+1] <- (-1)/(2*n + 1)*gamma[n+1]*exp(-K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2*t/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
  }
  sum_series238 <- sum(series238)  
  sum_series234 <- sum(series234)  
  sum_series230 <- sum(series230)
  i <- i+1
  A1[i] <- A1_0*(1 - 4/pi*sum_series238)
  DA2[i] <- DA2_0*(cosh(x*(l234/K)^0.5)/(cosh(l*l234/K)^0.5) - 4/pi*sum_series234)

  t0 <- 0
  series230_0 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
  beta234_0 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
  beta230_0 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
  gamma_0 <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length_series+1)
  for (n in 0:length_series){
    beta234_0[n+1] <- 1 + 4*l234*(l^2)/((2*n + 1)^2)*pi^2*K
    beta230_0[n+1] <- l230 - l234 - K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2/(4*l^2)
    gamma_0[n+1] <- l230*(1/(beta230[n+1] + l234) + (U48_0 - 1)*exp(-l234*t0)/(beta234[n+1]*beta230[n+1]))
    # series230_0[n+1] <- (-1)^n/(2*n + 1)*gamma[n+1]*exp(-K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2*t0/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
    series230_0[n+1] <- (-1)/(2*n + 1)*gamma[n+1]*exp(-K*(2*n + 1)^2*pi^2*t0/(4*l^2))*cos((2*n + 1)/2*pi*x/l)
  }
  sum_series230_0 <- sum(series230_0)
  f[i] <- - A1_0*(1 + (U48_0 - 1)*cosh(x*(l234/K)^0.5)/(cosh(l*(l234/K)^0.5) - 4/pi*sum_series230_0))*exp(-l230*t)
  A3[i] <- f[i] + A1_0*(1 + (U48_0 - 1)*cosh(x*(l234/K)^0.5)/(cosh(l*(l234/K)^0.5) - 4/pi*sum_series230))
}
A2 <- DA2 + A1
U48calc <- A2/A1
Th0U8calc <- A3/A1
Th0U4calc <- A3/A2

# create vectors to show data across the bone, not just 1/2 the bone
x_vec <- c(rev(-x_vec/l), x_vec/l) 
U48calc <- c(rev(U48calc), U48calc)
Th0U8calc <- c(rev(Th0U8calc), Th0U8calc)
Th0U4calc <- c(rev(Th0U4calc), Th0U4calc)
U48meas <- c(rev(U48meas), U48meas)
Th0U8meas <- c(rev(Th0U8meas), Th0U8meas)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x_vec, U48calc, Th0U8calc, Th0U4calc, U48meas, Th0U8meas))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x_vec, Th0U8calc), colour = 'red', size=3) + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x_vec, Th0U8meas), colour = 'blue', size=3) +
  xlab("Normalised distance from the center of the bone") +
  ylab("(230Th/238U)")
ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x_vec, U48calc), colour = 'red', size=3) + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x_vec, U48meas), colour = 'blue', size=3) +
  xlab("Normalised distance from the center of the bone") +
  ylab("(234U/238U)")
```

Comment: That's almost 200 lines of code! Can you make a **minimal example**?
 And maybe describe your process in words with a little more detail than "using `optim`"? What's your model equation? What's your loss function? What are the parameters? Why are you hard-coding things like `beta234_0[n+1] <- 1 + 4*l234*(l^2)/((2*n + 1)^2)*pi^2*K`, it's likely full of bugs that we'll never be able because who knows what `beta234_0` is supposed to be?

Comment: Also, please don't put lines like `rm(list = ls())` in your example code - no one wants to copy and run that by mistake.

Comment: this is a bit more complicated than a single model equation. While technically the equation to be minimised is `fmin <- sum((U48calc - U48meas)^2 + (Th0U8calc - Th0U8meas)^2 )` there are many other things that come into play to compute `U48calc` and `Th0U8calc`, hence why I shared the whole code. All equations have been checked and tested in a separate code (forward model). I think I'm going to go back to code in Matlab... 90% of the time I ask for help with R on SO, people are whinging instead of trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, normally I wouldn't consider this an answer, but it's too long for comments.

> tips on how to improve the fit?

- Two of the estimates are on the boundaries. Here's how the estimates compare to the bounds you gave:

  ```
       est lbound   ubound
  1.00e-12  1e-14  1.0e-12  estimate = upper bound
  1.00e+04  1e+04  6.0e+04  estimate = lower bound
  1.22e+00  1e+00  1.3e+00  nicely in the middle
  ```

Estimates on boundaries are usually bad. You should think about where the bounds come from and make sure they are set accurately.

- Parameters have extremely different scales. This is bad for `optim`, the gradient-based methods work best when a 1-unit change in any parameter has a roughly similar effect as a 1-unit change in another parameter. You can supply the `parscale` argument to automatically rescale them. The `?optim` help says "*Optimization is performed on `par/parscale` and these should be comparable in the sense that a unit change in any element produces about a unit change in the scaled value*". These don't have to be anywhere close to exact, but getting the parameter ranges close to the same order of magnitude could help a lot.
- Bounds are always less desirable than unbounded parameter values. Similar to the rescaling, you could scale your parameters to make the bounds (0,1) and then apply a logit transform to map it to (-Inf, Inf). Then you can estimate those unbounded parameters and apply the inverse transform to get the values on your original scale. This gives you more flexibility because you can use any of the methods, not just L-BFGS.
- Use other `control` arguments to try to diagnose issues and improve performance. Turn the `trace` on to get a better idea of what's going on. Maybe reduce the tolerances and increase the maximum iterations.
- Use `optimx` instead. [In this nice interview](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-optimR-john-nash/), John Nash, the author of `optim` recommends people use his `optimx` package for better performance and robustness.